# How to get video length using JMF?

Tags: java, video-processing, jmf

I'm using JMF and I wonder if there is a way of getting the length of the movie
I'm playing in HH:mm:ss or in long format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player extends Controller that extends Duration that declares method

`Time   getDuration()`:

Here is quotation from its javadoc:
Get the duration of the media represented by this object.

Shortly create player and then invoke its `getDuration()`